# How to get path of uploaded image in Octobercms backend?

Tags: octobercms

I'm having trouble with image upload at the backend with octoberCMS.
The image actually uploads, but I need to save the image path along with my model. I'm not able to get the full path, at most all I'm able to get is:

> /storage/app/uploads/public//

Please how do I obtain the full path to the uploaded image?

Answer (score 0):

Add function to your model :

```
public function getAll(){
    return self::get();
}
```

After add onInit() function in your page :

```
function onInit() {
    $model = new Author\PluginName\Models\ClassName(); // change path to your model
    $this['alldata']= $model->getAll();

}
```

After that you get all data with image on your page.
You can get image path this way :

```
{% for item in alldata %}

   {{ item.fileupload1.path}} // change 'fileupload1' to your file input name   

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Everything ok but I think item.fileupload1.path is not correct, it should be item.fileupload1.getPath()

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get path from media manager section by using media finder uploader object; you can use this code.

```
Config::get('cms.storage.media.path')
```